# Why are there holes in the ocean?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, there is a hole which appears in the ocean.

[image]

Why is this hole here? Is it known what created it? And, are there other holes like it?

Comment: this will be interesting, it was a special *IIRC*

Comment: For one, there is the hole at Enies Lobby.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hole in the ocean from your image is from the first [One Piece special](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Special_1).

As for the reason why it was there, this is what I could find:

> She opens it only to find just a skull inside. Usopp reads the back of
>   the skull, which engraves about a treasure that can make anyone's
>   dream come true. It lies deep in the ocean's naval. Then a large hole
>   begins to form near the crater they crashed into, so Usopp, Nami, and
>   Sanji prepare themselves in a diving barrel to explore the cavity in
>   the sea.

So far we have seen two other "holes" in the anime.
The first of them being the whirlpool that is formed by the [Knock Up Stream](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Knock_Up_Stream).

The second one is seen in the [Maubeugemour Sea](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Maubeugemour_Sea) in [episode 575](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_575) (this is a filler for the [One Piece Film Z](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Film_Z)).

[image: Hole in Ocean]

Comment: there is a big hole in Enies Lobby y'know